# Update global C struct using only one function without passing whole data structure

Tags: c, database, database-design, persistence

I am developing a database access layer to store data of software subsystems. The database interface has two functions, `database_get()` and `database_set()`. They take two arguments, first is a ID that identifies the software component and the second argument is a typedef struct that holds the new settings for this software component. Then i have:

```
#define COMPONENT1_ID 7
typedef struct
{
    int member1;
    char member2;
    char member3;

}   COMPONENT1_STRUCT_T ;
```

I can store and retrieve persistent data calling the `database_set(COMPONENT1_ID, (void *) &new_struct)` and `database_get(COMPONENT1_ID, (void *) &new_struct)` functions. It works the same for storing data from any other software subsystem using this database.

Now i am developing APIs to manage this software subsystems. This APIs are used by the user interfaces. The API of a software subsystem is taking care of performing all the logic behind the component and also calling the database to make its data persistent. I have developed a function for the API which carries out the operation and finally call a function like this:

```
int save_new_member1_db(int member1);
{ 
    COMPONENT1_STRUCT_T new_setting;

    database_get(COMPONENT1_ID, (void *)&new_setting);
    new_setting.member1 = member1;
    database_set(COMPONENT1_ID, (void *)&new_setting); 
}
```

I wonder if i can avoid creating a new function to update each member data in the database.

Also I dont want a big function taking the whole struct or all members of the struct if it means the subsystem API gets reduced to one function. The subsystem can be a LED display and its API could be different methods doing one thing as update_led_display_color(const LED_DISPLAY_COLOR new color), `update_led_display_font(const LED_DISPLAY_FONT cur_font)`, `get_led_display_font(LED_DISPLAY_FONT *cur_font)` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to need some kind of mapping between a symbolic constant representing a member and information you need to set that member. You could use something like your "COMPONENT1_ID" for each member and have an array of size+offset information for each member like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <string.h>

// in header file (or wherever so that it is visible to
// the definition of "Test_save_member" and not a part of
// the subsystem API)
#define TEST_ID 7 


// in a c file (in your database implementation, I assume)
typedef struct
{
    int mem1;
    char mem2;
    char mem3;
} Test;

// for sure in header file exposed in your subsystem API
typedef enum
{
    MEM1,
    MEM2,
    MEM3,
    NUM_MEMBERS
} TestMember;

// in c file (in your database implementation, I assume again)

typedef struct
{
    size_t offset;
    size_t size;
} MemberInfo;

static MemberInfo member_info[NUM_MEMBERS] =
{
    { offsetof(Test, mem1), sizeof(int) },
    { offsetof(Test, mem2), sizeof(char) },
    { offsetof(Test, mem3), sizeof(char) }
};

// also a part of your subsystem API
int Test_save_member(TestMember member, void* value)
{
    if (!value || member < 0 || member >= NUM_MEMBERS))
        return 0;

    Test new_setting;
    database_get(TEST_ID, (void *)&new_setting);
    MemberInfo info = member_info[member];
    memcpy((char*)(&new_setting) + info.offset, value, info.size);
    database_set(TEST_ID, (void *)&new_setting);
    return 1;
}

// subsystem API usage
int main(void)
{
    int new_mem1 = 5;
    Test_save_member(MEM1, &new_mem1);
    return 0;
}
```

Depending upon whether you want to edit your database functions, the amount of coupling you want to deal with, etc, this could change drastically; I don't think, however, that you can get away without some type of mapping given the constraints you mentioned.

This particular implementation would disallow passing literals, but that shouldn't be too big of an issue (to deal with or work around).

Comment: Great! I think the only solution is this way or any other that looks like this one dealing with the offset and size of the members with a table driven method.